# SonarQube under Nginx sub-location

Tags: nginx, sonarqube

Has I try to create a continuous integration server, i have many tools to install, but i want to use a single DN for all of it.
So I'm trying to host each tool under a sub-location of my DN (ex : my-domain.org/sonar, my-domain.org/packages, etc...)

As an hosting newbie, I'm facing a very boring issue, with SonarQube access.
The tool is installed, and i can access it with my-domain.org:9000

But my Nginx configuration does not seems to be convenient, has the expected SonarQube page gives me a SonarQube 404.

Here is my Nginx vhost configuration :

```
server {
  listen *:80;
  server_name my-domain.org;

  #some other tools configuration

  location /sonarqube {
    proxy_pass             http://localhost:9000;
    proxy_redirect         http://localhost:9000 /sonarqube;
  }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: We're using a similar reverse proxy configuration for nemo.sonarqube.org, so this should work. Could you attach to this thread the error message returned by the SonarQube server ?

Comment: Sure :
The page you were looking for doesn't exist.
You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.
Go back to the homepage

And the link point to : http://www.my-domain.org

Comment: This is also an extract of the access log :
127.0.0.1 - - [23/09/2014:10:19:20 +0200] "GET /sonarqube HTTP/1.0" 404 1039 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36"

Comment: So in fact the error page you're talking about is not delivered by SonarQube but by Nginx itslef ? Whatever is the reason, looks like the definition of the virtual server in the Nginx configuration is not taken into account.

Comment: No, this page is delivered by SonarQube, I'm sure about that. Do you think that the Nginx configuration of the other tools may interfere with SonarQube ?

Comment: I'm sorry, don't have any other idea :(

Comment: Sorry for reopening this question, but have you managed to find an answer to your question? I'm having the exact same problem.

Comment: Hi, I did not get any answer to this question... And I cannot access the environment any more. Sorry

Answer (score 15):

I faced the exact same issue today and solved it with the configurations below. The problem though, depending on your configuration of sonarqube this could be slightly different, but here we go:

sonar.properties

```
sonar.web.context=/sonarqube
sonar.web.port=9000
```

sites-available/default.conf

```
location /sonarqube {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;

  # set header
  proxy_set_header        Host $host;
  proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_connect_timeout   150;
  proxy_send_timeout      100;
  proxy_read_timeout      100;
  proxy_buffers           4 32k;
  client_max_body_size    8m;
  client_body_buffer_size 128k;

   proxy_redirect http://localhost:9000 http://$yourlan$/sonarqube;
}
```

Nginx server should listen on Port 80 and `server_name` should be `$yourlan$`

Answer (score 0):

Change the sonar.properties context.path:

```
sonar.web.context=/sonarqube
```

And simply use nginx conf:

```
location /sonarqube {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9000/sonarqube;
}
```

Comment: This only it gives a 404 error.